# Does Heart of Fenrir trigger when carrier is dead and/or when revived?

Tags: werewolv.es

Does someone turn Omegawolf in GY if holding HoF when wolfpack has died?

---

If answer to above question is 'No', then what happens if: Holder of Heart of Fenrir (in GY) gets revived. Wolfpack has died while this person was in GY.

Does the HoF trigger after revive? When does it trigger?

(Underlying question is whether HoF can trigger every night or only after a member of wolfpack dies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was tested, the HoF doesn't activate while dead, but it activates the nightfall after your revive if there are still no wolves alive.

Credits to: Niji, Shabas, Diamond Dove, Rox and Kirschstein